# Python numbers above 2**32 or 2**64

Tags: integer, overflow, integer-overflow

My understanding of computer architecture was the maximum number a computer can handle is 2^32 or 2^64, but I am able to produce numbers significantly above this, such as  `14242792383964888162918480513432465216409371640403009729971037612045113415478719007639881209041451055630074000655093473974722206675223109929434400259100512062680086347153555148539548552831624261944567042435944993535084132588196941322891072406503377213352323037077384970994853089450777507879083442634420291861180736024127002634265953304576`

How is python able to produce such a large number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does python represent such large integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22875067/how-does-python-represent-such-large-integers)